# How to hide Domain URL from FB Shared link from Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am Sharing a link from my Android application Using this code

```
            ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Memory Match")
                .setContentUrl(
                        Uri.parse("http://dl.flipkart.com/dl/"))
                .setImageUrl(
                        Uri.parse("http://cybercom.co.in/mm/fb_banner.png"))
                .setContentDescription("Download Memory Match game").build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

and I am getting result on my fb wall like this

[image]

but I do not want to show domain name(rounded red) on wall like above image and I want like flipkart has done like image below

[image]

they are showing text How can I do like that, where should I set that text i rounded green

Comment: I would take that link and put it in the facebook debugger and see their configuration, this should give you an idea of what meta tags they are using.

Comment: hello, did you get the answer to this? I have the same problem with this